# How to rewrite rules NginX in this example?

Tags: api, nginx, url-rewriting

I am creating an API to feed some apps.

So the app could call these possible URLs to get information from the database;

```
mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/list_tblname1.json.php
mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/list_tblname1.json.php?type=arr
mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/list_tblname2.json.php
mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/list_tblname2.json.php?type=arr
```

In php I have already the code that grabs the `tblname` from the URL and give me back all the table content. It works good (it is not the final version).
But now I find myself copying and pasting the same code for each page where the URL points to. Here is the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json');
include_once '../../../../class/db.php';
$verb=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$filePath=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$split1 = explode("/", $filePath);

preg_match("/(?<=_)[^.]+/", $split1[5], $matches);
$tableName = $matches[0];

if ($verb=="GET") {

        header("HTTP/1.1 200 ok");

        if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=="arr"){
            echo db::get_list($tableName,'arr');//Reply ARRAY  
        }
        else{
            echo db::get_list($tableName);//Reply JSON  
        }
}
else{
        die("Nothing for you at this page!");        
    }
```

I mean, I have the same code inside each these pages.

```
list_tblname1.json.php
list_tblname2.json.php
```

I am not sure how to solve this situation but I think that this is case for 
rewrite rules.

So, I think a possible solution is to create one page that could call 
`returncontent.php` for example and create rules in the server that should point to the same page when certanlly pages are requested and pass the parameter  `$tableName` to the page. I think I should pass the regex to my server and grab the `$tableName` with $_GET[] (I think) inside `returncontent.php`.

I am not sure about it.

I am using NginX.

How to implement it in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, it's bad practice to parse a URI in NginX and pass the result downstream.

Rather: `mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/returncontent.php?file=list_tblname2.json`

No changes to NginX needed. Parse the query param (`file`) in PHP.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to consider an ORM, e.g. propelorm.org

Comment: your idea was nice and clean. Save me a ton of code.!

Comment: by the way I did `mysite.com/api/v1/get/menus/returncontent.php?tbl=tblname.type`. That can be `?tbl=tblname.json` or `?tbl=tblname.arr`.